# After remove search box in select2 keyboard select option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using select2 in my project. As per design, I am removed the search box in selectbox2, but after removed search box, keyboard select option not works. Could any one help me to fix this. - Thanks

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select2 Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css">
  </head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div>Skills</div>
    <select id="skills" style="width: 200px">
      <option>html</option>
      <option>css</option>
      <option>js</option>
    </select>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#skills').select2({
          minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/kipuzet/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$('#skills').select2()
```

use

```
$('#skills').select()
```

That should work.

Comment: Not works. `$.fn.select2` Man that plugin name it self `select2` then how `select` will work.

Comment: .Select() is a `JQUERY` function , so that should work Fine. here is the reference link . https://api.jquery.com/select/